# BASH if conditions

Tags: bash, scripting

I did ask a question before. The answer made sense, but I could never get it to work. And now I gotta get it working. But I cannot figure out BASH's if statements. What am I doing wrong below:

```
START_TIME=9
STOP_TIME=17
HOUR=$((`date +"%k"`))
if [[ "$HOUR" -ge "9" ]] && [[ "$HOUR" -le "17" ]] && [[ "$2" != "-force" ]] ; then
    echo "Cannot run this script without -force at this time"
    exit 1
fi
```

The idea is that I don't want this script to continue executing, unless forced to, during hours of 9am to 5pm. But it will always evaluate the condition to true and thus won't allow me to run the script.

./script.sh [action] (-force)

Thx

Edit: The output of set -x:

```
$ ./test2.sh restart
+ START_TIME=9
+ STOP_TIME=17
++ date +%k
+ HOUR=11
+ [[ 11 -ge 9 ]]
+ [[ 11 -le 17 ]]
+ [[ '' != \-\f\o\r\c\e ]]
+ echo 'Cannot run this script without -force at this time'
Cannot run this script without -force at this time
+ exit 1
```

and then with -force

```
$ ./test2.sh restart -force
+ START_TIME=9
+ STOP_TIME=17
++ date +%k
+ HOUR=11
+ [[ 11 -ge 9 ]]
+ [[ 11 -le 17 ]]
+ [[ '' != \-\f\o\r\c\e ]]
+ echo 'Cannot run this script without -force at this time'
Cannot run this script without -force at this time
+ exit 1
```

Comment: What version of bash are you using?  It works fine on mine: 3.2.49.

Comment: It's GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu). I feel really stupid that the above won't work. Always goes into error mode. Have no idea why.

Comment: "error mode" - What do you mean by that? Is there an error message?

Comment: I meant, it always evaluates the condition to true and asks to use -force (from running script POV that would be error mode).

Comment: I just noticed, on the second run with -force parameter. "$2" is getting evaluated to blank for some reason. Is `force` a reserved word in bash of sorts?

Comment: Seems more like something before your `set -x` is clobbering `$2`. Check for `shift`, and `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
START_TIME=9
STOP_TIME=17
HOUR=$(date +"%k")
if (( $HOUR >= $START_TIME && $HOUR <= $STOP_TIME )) && [[ "$2" != "-force" ]] ; then
    echo "Cannot run this script without -force at this time"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Note that having `STOP_TIME` set to 17 will prevent the script from running all the way until 17:59. You may need to change that if you want to be able to run it during the interval 17:00-17:59 (inclusive) or test for hours and minutes for more precision.

Comment: OK - it seems to be working. Yes, I don't want to have that script executed up until 6pm, hence the <= 17. Big thanks! But can you explain what I was doing wrong? Just feeling very stupid that cannot figure out what seems to be the simplest possible task.

Comment: I can't see any reason why your version doesn't work. Add `set -x` right before that section and `set +x` right after and edit your question to show the resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

Use *-a* instead of *&&*:

```
if [ $HOUR -ge $START_TIME -a $HOUR -le $STOP_TIME -a "_$2" != "_-force" ]; then
    echo "Cannot run without -force at this hour"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Your code is OK since all the values are known, controlled, or guarded, but, in general, it is better to use either `[[ … -a … ]]` or `[ … ] && [ … ]`. See the Application Usage section of the [POSIX specification for *test* ](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).

The problem is that `[ … ]` can be confused by values that look like operators since it parses for operators after expansion (because it was originally an external command), but `[[ … ]]` can parse for operators before expansion (because it is defined as built-in to the shells that support it).